# nusoap simple server

Tags: php, nusoap

Hi i am using this code for nusoap server but when i call the server in web browser it shows message "This service does not provide a Web description" Here is the code

```
<?
//call library
require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');

//using soap_server to create server object
$server = new soap_server;

//register a function that works on server
$server->register('hello');

// create the function
function hello($name)
{
if(!$name){
return new soap_fault('Client','','Put your name!');
}

$result = "Hello, ".$name;
return $result;
}

// create HTTP listener
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

exit();
?>
```

An help ...

Comment: Well, did you ask the WSDL service to *do* anything? Or just visit it in a browser? All it is doing is telling you that there are no web pages to serve, but if you send it some SOAP that it is expecting, maybe it will work...

Comment: i just want to show xml from my server.php file

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please change your code to,

```
<?php
//call library
require_once('nusoap.php');
$URL       = "www.test.com";
$namespace = $URL . '?wsdl';
//using soap_server to create server object
$server    = new soap_server;
$server->configureWSDL('hellotesting', $namespace);

//register a function that works on server
$server->register('hello');

// create the function
function hello($name)
{
    if (!$name) {
        return new soap_fault('Client', '', 'Put your name!');
    }
    $result = "Hello, " . $name;
    return $result;
}
// create HTTP listener
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
exit();
?>
```

You didnt Define namespace..

Please see simple example here :-

http://patelmilap.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/soap-simple-object-access-protocol/

Comment: As of PHP 7  $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is removed. So instead of 
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);  use $server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));

Answer (score 5):

The web browser is not calling the Web service - you could create a PHP client :

```
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
// Create the client instance
$client = new soapclient('your server url');
// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call('hello', array('name' => 'StackOverFlow'));
// Display the result
print_r($result);
```

This should display `Hello, StackOverFlow`

Update

To create a WSDL you need to add the following :

```
$server->configureWSDL(<webservicename>, <namespace>);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use nusoap_client

```
<?php
// Pull in the NuSOAP code
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
// Create the client instance
$client = new nusoap_client('your server url'); // using nosoap_client
// Call the SOAP method
$result = $client->call('hello', array('name' => 'Pingu'));
// Display the result
print_r($result)
?>
```