# Soap Api with Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, soap

How to create soap API containing data from database in laravel?

I have done rest API but the client need SOAP API to implement it in a queue management system. I don't know much about soap and XML.

Comment: You have to consume or provide data ? What have you done ? What is your kwnoledge ? I have an raw code, using the native SoapClient from php (it's pretty simple indeed)

Comment: https://packalyst.com/packages/tag/soap

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package: https://github.com/econea/nusoap, instantiate a server and register your endpoints

```
$server = new \nusoap_server();
$server->configureWSDL('TestService', "urn:delos", url('ws-delos') , 'rpc');

$this->server->register('Receive_products',
            [
                'id' => 'xsd:int',
                'name' => 'xsd:string',
                'category' => 'xsd:string',
            ],
            [
                'output' => 'xsd:string'
            ],
            "urn:delos",
            "urn:delos#Receive_products", <--- this function must be registered global in Laravel 
            "rpc",
            'encoded',
            "Receive products data");
```

Check for other aswers with this implementation: 
[nusoap simple server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130117/nusoap-simple-server)